# Importing data from Excel to SQL table using button

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have an Excel file that looks like the below

```
System   |   Status

Test         OK
Test2        Down
Test3        OK
```

I also have a SQL server table with the same columns.

What I want is a button on the Excel sheet that once clicked, will truncate the SQL table and insert the values from the Excel table into the SQL table.

I have tried the below step but I am struggling due to my lack of understanding of developing in Excel (I am a SQL developer)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/84725bcb-328d-4aed-8b95-d2c34dc46be4/need-to-update-sql-server-table-on-click-of-excel-button?forum=sqldataaccess

Any help would be massively appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: "struggling" isn't a problem description we can help with. Please show your code and identify precisely what is going wrong when you execute it.

Comment: I don't understand the code. I don't understand how I would modify it to meet my requirements. I don't know how else to explain that? I am fine with anything SQL but understanding how to translate the code above isn't something I can do. I.E does "Replace(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)" select the first row in Excel??

Comment: have you tried to study any Excel/VBA documentation or tutorials? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells

Comment: @Jess8766 `Replace(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), "'", "''")` is used to escape quotation ie, a single quotation is replaced with '',.. since you're familiar with SQL to to Insert value **Kevin's Dog** we do `'Kevin''s Dog'`. 

The whole VBA code basically iterates through all the rows in the excel tab and prepares multiple update statements (in your case it should be insert)

Answer (score 0):

We have created an Excel Add-In for updating tables from Excel to SQL Server which have a Save button that will save your changes in Excel to the mapped table in SQL Server. The Add-In is built for non-technical people so it is rather straightforward to set up the spreadsheet without having to write any code.

It won't truncate the table, but there are a couple of ways to update the table which hopefully will give you the same result. Without knowing your exact use case, I would propose to either just do an update of the table from Excel if that meets your requirements, or add a timestamp column and let the Add-In write the timestamp to each updated/inserted row and then only use the last updated/inserted rows (you can also let the Add-In delete all previous rows after a new insert).

If that's of interest, you can [read more here](https://sqlspreads.com/) and download a free trial.

Disclaimer: I'm the founder of the company.